# is there aes 256 with cbc encryption in ubuntu/linux/unix?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I would like to create an IV encryption with aes 256  and cbc pkcs7 padding. I would like to ask if there is a library in linux that implements this type of encryption. I don't want to add dependency files/ libraries. THX! APPRECIATE

If there is nothing like this includes in Linux(I am working on Ubuntu) could you please specify a simple and easy way to do this encryption in c++ (add it's files and headers in my code). THX. APPRECIATE!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/crypto.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Crypto++
http://www.cryptopp.com/

I use it for the RSA and find it satisfactory.